# Running URL after Heroku Deployment displays application error

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, backend, web-deployment

I've created the project on GoormIDE and am trying to deploy it using Heroku, however it is giving error as

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
>   You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command  heroku logs
>   --tail

I've tried running the application from Goorm itself and it is running without any error.

The Heroku logs say that

> W 2020-06-04T13:40:13.026765+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   Server running at port 3000 2020-06-04T13:40:13.200053+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Connected 2020-06-04T13:41:09.692255+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
>   60 seconds of launch 2020-06-04T13:41:09.717907+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Stopping process with SIGKILL 2020-06-04T13:41:09.833400+00:00
>   heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
>   2020-06-04T13:41:09.879805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2020-06-04T13:41:11.348533+00:00 heroku[router]:
>   at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=immense-harbor-74512.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=2bfa2066-edf0-4c28-bee0-b84522cae634 fwd= "27.60.111.103"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=httpsthen,

What is the problem and how to fix it

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @Saddy I've updated the question and added the logs

Answer (score 0):

Procfile
web:guinicorn python app.py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).